# Using a pointer in a struct

Tags: c

While I was inputting "stuList[1].name", an error occurred and the program crashed.  How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct student
    {
        int id;
        char *name;
        float percentage;
    } student;

int main()
{
    student stuList[3];
    stuList[0].name = "vermidonhapic"; 
    stuList[2].name = "didiervermiyer";

    scanf("%s\n",&stuList[1].name);

    printf(" name is: %s \n", stuList[0].name);
    printf(" name is: %s \n", stuList[2].name);  
    printf(" name is: %s \n", stuList[1].name);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` with a `"%s"` format is extremely dangerous, even if the pointer points to properly allocated memory.  It will read an arbitrarily long string into the destination buffer; there's no way to prevent it from writing past the end of your array.

Answer (score 2):

`stuList[1].name` is an invalid pointer as it has not been initialized to point to a valid object.

You should dynamically allocate memory (through `malloc` function) for `stuList[1].name` so `scanf` could write to an allocated object.

```
stuList[1].name = malloc(size_enough_to_store_your_string);
```

Moreover,  `stuList[1].name` is a pointer to `char` so you should use `stuList[1].name` and not `&stuList[1].name` (pointer to a pointer to `char`) in your `scanf` function call.

Comment: @amit thanks, I misread the string literal pointers assignments. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In this command: `scanf("%s\n",&stuList[1].name);`

You are scanning string from input without actually allocating the required memory.

This results in trying to write the data in an unkown address, which is not yours, which results in a segmentation fault.

To fix it, first allocate memory: `stuList[1].name = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);`, and only after: scan the string from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is just a pointer that isn't pointing to memory you own, so writing through it will corrupt memory. You need to allocate some memory on it with `malloc()`, or make it an array rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate memory for `stuList[1].name`. You need to allocate it from the heap with `malloc` or stack allocate it.

```
stuList[1].name = malloc(MAX_NAME_LENGTH);//heap allocation
//use stuList[1].name
free(stuList[1].name);

char buffer[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];//stack allocation
stuList[1].name = buffer;
```

I've omitted all error checking, protection against over-running buffers etc.

Since `stuList[1].name` is a pointer, you are incorrect in taking its address in your `scanf`.